# my header font won't apply put my p font will

Tags: html, css, fonts

i have been busy with my website again and i have been adding fonts.
guinfo and beyondsky,
the only problem is that quinfo does apply on my paragraphs but beyond sky not on my headers.

here is all of the code https://mega.co.nz/#!wkQXzDTY!WnUrAbtbn6awROUb64bNll6_kUzaSkq8T8PVQKEdfqs (you may not publish it only help me)

here's my code in css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'beyond_skyregular';
src: url('/Users/roderik/Desktop/sites/tisgametijd site/fonts web/beyondsk_complete-webfont.eot');
src: url('/Users/roderik/Desktop/sites/tisgametijd site/fonts web/beyondsk_complete-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/Users/roderik/Desktop/sites/tisgametijd site/fonts web/beyondsk_complete-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/Users/roderik/Desktop/sites/tisgametijd site/fonts web/beyondsk_complete-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/Users/roderik/Desktop/sites/tisgametijd site/fonts web/beyondsk_complete-webfont.svg#beyond_skyregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

h1  {
font-family:beyond_skyregular;  
color:#ffffff;
}
h2  {
    font-family:beyond_skyregular;  
    color:#ffffff;
}
h3  {
    font-family:beyond_skyregular;  
    color:#ffffff;
}
h4  {
    font-family:beyond_skyregular;  
    color:#ffffff;
}
h5  {
    font-family:beyond_skyregular;  
    color:#ffffff;
}
h6  {
    font-family:beyond_skyregular;  
    color:#ffffff;
```

Comment: It looks to me a path problem, you are working on a localhost dev environment? Try a relative path or google web font.

Comment: quifno isn't a webfont and works fine and quinfo has the same path

Comment: Problem only in Firefox?

Comment: safari, chrome, bbedit preview

Comment: mind show us your working demo or your generated html?

Comment: generated ive written it all and i will upload a demo

Comment: i got it all right here https://mega.co.nz/#!wkQXzDTY!WnUrAbtbn6awROUb64bNll6_kUzaSkq8T8PVQKEdfqs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Just tried that on my dev environment, screen shot as below, which loads both fonts correctly. What I did was to replace your path /Users/roderik/Desktop/sites/tisgametijd site/fonts web/...
with this 
/fonts web/...

Let me know if this solves your problem.
On another note I'd suggest you put all @ rules at the top which is more reader friendly. And keep all css files in the same folder, not document root of each directory, i.e. home, blog etc.

Comment: eeeeh what are those rules?

Comment: adn halo is stil not in the beyondsky style

Comment: i did put this on top of my css code @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {

}

Comment: 1. I meant your @font-face rules;2. obviously the font is correctly loaded, if you comment out the font-family: beyond_skyregular you will see a default font by your browser, so this might be you are using an incorrect font file, you can try another source. I did compare it with beyondsky and I agree it does not look like it.

Comment: yeah i guess i leave it at how it looks now i have been searching for a little resize thing and i found a javascript code for that